# Updating parent table from referencing child

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a webplatform from which a teacher can assign tasks to students.
Each task contains at least one or more sub-tasks.

`Task_data` is a table linking a task to each student and may contain data for each student´s progress on said task.

`Sub_task_data` is a table linking the task-data to each sub-task and may contain data for each student´s progress on said sub-task.

I have the following table structures:

```
=====================            =====================
|    Task_data      |            |   Sub_task_data   |
=====================            =====================
|     (PK) id       |            |     (PK) id       |
|   (FK) task_id    |  1 ----- n | (FK) sub_task_id  |
|  (FK) member_id   |            | (FK) task_data_id |
|     updated_on    |            |    is_completed   |
=====================            =====================
```

The tables `members`, `task` and `subtask` are not illustrated as it's not necessary here.

I'm wondering if the `updated_on` row can somehow automatically be updated with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` whenever a row in the `Sub_task_data` table (with the relevant Foreign Key) gets updated?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, google for "mysql trigger".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_time_taskdata 
AFTER UPDATE ON Sub_task_data FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Task_data
       SET updated_on = NOW()
     WHERE id = NEW.task_data_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Refer [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!